# How to divide a point set into a set of triangles according to a centerpoint?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, geometry, python

15 Points in red are randomly generated.

The point in blue is called a 'centerpoint', which means any closed half space contains it also contains 15/(2+1)=5 points in red.

The question is how can I divide the points in red to a set of triangles so that the point in blue locates inside every triangle.

If the size of the point set is not a multiple of three, then just round down.

I need an algorithm that can be used in every randomly generated point set, which confused me most.

Great Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.